# .bashrc seems not executed when logged in from a relay machine

Tags: ssh, bashrc

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 in Virtualbox. I have 4 identically installed Xubuntu 18.04 virtual machines each doing different jobs. I have account A on machine One and account B on machine Two. In both accounts, I have custom color prompts and custom $PATH. I ssh to account A from a terminal on machine C, and I get my usual color prompt and $PATH as expected. However, when I continue on from account A on machine One to ssh to account B on machine Two, I lose my usual color prompt and $PATH that I expect from account B. All I get is generic system prompt and $PATH. I tried this from machine D to A to B as well, and I get the same result. Seems like my .bashrc was not executed when I login from a relay machine. So, why is that?

Comment: Your *local* `.bashrc` won't get sourced in a *remote* shell; and `.bashrc` won't necessarily be sourced at all for a remote *login shell* - it depends on the remote `.profile` and/or `.bash_profile`

Comment: On the target machines, `bash -x ~/.bashrc` will show you what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much steeldriver and waltinator ! I linked .bashrc to .bash_profile and it now works. Thanks !!